# Cannot find module 'typescript' on running docker container

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nestjs, production

I'm facing an issue while running my docker container for a NestJS project since yesterday for unknown reasons, I can build and run `start:prod` or `start:dev` without any issue locally, but when it comes to deploying it to prod (running the container on docker), I'm getting this error:

**The error :**

```bash
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/typescript.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/services/i18n.service.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/i18n.module.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/index.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/translation/translation.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/mylerz/mylerz.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/orders/order.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/wallet/wallet.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/users/user.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/notification/notification.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/app.service.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/app.controller.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/app.module.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/typescript.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/typescript.js',
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js',
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/services/i18n.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/i18n.module.js',
    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/index.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/translation/translation.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/mylerz/mylerz.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/orders/order.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/wallet/wallet.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/users/user.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/notification/notification.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/app.service.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/app.controller.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/app.module.js',
    '/usr/src/app/dist/main.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

**My `Dockerfile`:**

```yaml
FROM node:alpine AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:alpine AS production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -omit=dev

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

RUN npm run postinstall

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

**My `package.json` :**

```json
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.1.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.1.4",
    "@sentry/minimal": "^6.19.7",
    "@sentry/node": "^7.60.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.60.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.9",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "buffer-to-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "cache-manager": "^5.2.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.1",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^4.0.0",
    "nestjs-i18n": "^10.2.6",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-strategy": "^1.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "slugify": "^1.6.6",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.1.10",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.1.2",
    "@types/buffer-to-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/cron": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "@types/randomstring": "^1.1.8",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "29.6.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I searched about the issue on both Github Issues and SO but none of them provided me a solution about my specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in order to fix this issue, at least temporarily for users that are in the same situation with [this package](https://github.com/toonvanstrijp/nestjs-i18n)

With using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), you can remove this line

```js
__exportStar(require("./typescript"), exports);
```

from this file `node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js`

Simply add this file `nestjs-i18n+10.3.1.patch` to your patches directory with this content:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js b/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js
index 13bca8b..d1d0300 100644
--- a/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/nestjs-i18n/dist/utils/index.js
@@ -18,6 +18,5 @@ __exportStar(require("./context"), exports);
 __exportStar(require("./file"), exports);
 __exportStar(require("./format"), exports);
 __exportStar(require("./merge"), exports);
-__exportStar(require("./typescript"), exports);
 __exportStar(require("./util"), exports);
 //# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
\ No newline at end of file
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an issue with [this package](https://github.com/toonvanstrijp/nestjs-i18n/blob/main/package.json) which you can see lists typescript as a devDependency. The thing is, devDependencies are **not installed** when `NODE_ENV` is set to production which is why it works for you locally but not in Docker: you probably don't have your environment set to "production" on your dev machine. And the package [clearly imports from the typescript package](https://github.com/toonvanstrijp/nestjs-i18n/blob/bee66b95d1bb631aa9e84bf5dbbb07c07060f4bc/src/utils/typescript.ts#L1) meaning it should be a regular dependency not a devDependency. You may want to file a github issue if one doesn't already exist.

The solution in the meantime is to just install typescript some other way, e.g. by including it your project's own dependencies.

Comment: Adding Typescript to dependencies can be a temporary solution, but it was not worth it, I found a way to patch this problem, but your answer helped me to get it fixed.

Answer (score -3):

You don't have typescript installed inside your docker container, install it during the build by adding `RUN npm install -g typescript` in the Dockerfile